# MySQL: SLEEP injection

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if someone could help to understand this query, basically I'm aware about [SLEEP()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_sleep) function but I've never seen this implementation before.
Why there are no any results returned?

```
mysql> SELECT fname, lname FROM contacts WHERE fname = 'test' / SLEEP(1) / '';
Empty set, 14 warnings (7.00 sec)
```

Warnings:

```
Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'test'
...
```

Comment: The query makes no sense. Where did you get this from? I hardly believe this serves any useful purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No results are returned because, unsurprisingly, there are no records that meet the conditions of the WHERE clause.  `SLEEP()` will return 0 (if not interrupted), and all operands will be cast as doubles for the division operation (hence the warning about truncated incorrect double).  In essence, the query is the same as

```
SELECT fname, lname FROM contacts WHERE fname = 0 / 0 / 0;
```

Division by zero results in null, so you're basically looking for records where `fname = NULL`, which is never true.